# How to fix Composer [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Error

Tags: php, composer-php

How to fix the below error When updating composer every time

```
/*// composer Error
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%24fc1e20eb7ce69e30c5619d2a9d79fe3
  441318692407fc723631fb16e38063890.json" file could not be downloaded: faile
  d to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party d
  id not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
  ailed because connected host has failed to respond.

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no
-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
 [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--pre
fer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]... */
```

Comment: which composer's version are you using?

Comment: I am using composer version is 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Adding repositories in `composer.json` is working for me

```
{
    "repositories": [{
        "packagist": false
    }, {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org/"
    }],
    "require": {},
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    }
}
```